# jQuery Clone Issues

Tags: jquery, clone

Can someone check this out and tell me what's wrong...I just don't see it:

```
function getStates(){
var stateData;

$.getJSON("getStateData.php", function(data) {
    stateData = data;
    var theLastGroup = "";

    $("#groupList").empty();
    $("#stateList").empty();

    $.each(stateData, function(i,jsonData) {
        if( theLastGroup != jsonData.groupName )
        {
            $("#listModel").clone(true).removeAttr("id").attr("id", "Group_" + i).removeClass("hidden").appendTo($("#groupList"))
                .find(".url").attr("href", "#"+jsonData.groupName).end()
                .find(".groupName").html(jsonData.groupID);

            $("#groupModel").clone(true).removeAttr("id").removeClass("hidden").attr("id", jsonData.groupName).appendTo($("#stateList"));
        }


        $("#stateModel").clone(true).removeAttr("id").attr("id", jsonData.stateName).removeClass("hidden").appendTo($("#"+jsonData.groupName))
            .attr("sname", jsonData.stateName).attr("lat", jsonData.centerLat).attr("lon", jsonData.centerLon)
            .attr("zom", jsonData.zoom).html(jsonData.stateName);

        if( theLastGroup != jsonData.groupName )
        {
            theLastGroup = jsonData.groupName;
        }
    });
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});

}
```

...and the HTML that ends up calling the getStates() above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>My Page</title>

<link href="js_src/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js_src/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js_src/CTR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js_src/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js_src/mapNull.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js_src/functions.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    div.hidden {display:none;}
    li.hidden {display:none;}
    span.hidden {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<ul>
    <li id="listModel" class="hidden"><a class="url"><span class="groupName"></span></a></li>

    <div id="groupModel" class="hidden"></div>
    <span id="stateModel" class="hidden" sname="name" lat="0.0" lon="0.0" zom="7"></span>
</ul>

<body>
<h4>MyPage</h4>
<div id="tabs" style="height:100px" class="hidden">
    <h5>select a state...</h5>

    <ul id="groupList"></ul>
    <div id="stateList"></div>
</div>

<div id="map" style="float:left;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The getStates() function is called from the mapNull.js script when the page loads...

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you let us know what you've tried to debug it so far and what that's shown you.

Comment: What is your HTML markup? What is your data? What exactly do you want to happen? The more details to give us, the easier we can help you. If you can, it's even better if you put a simplified code sample to jsfiddle.net which replicates the issue.

Comment: Updated the question with more info...
For Debuggging, I have inserted alerts in various places. I DO get data back from the PHP call...and it is the data I expect. All that seems OK...just the clone does not appear to happen. I expect the tabs to be built once all the clones are done...

Comment: Can you describe the expected outcome of the above code and what you are actually seeing?  The JSON from getStateData.php would be helpful as well.

Comment: The expected outcome is to have a 'dynamic' jQuery tab that gets filled with the JSON data.

The JSON data is like this: (centerLat,centerLon,zoom,stateName,groupName)
"139.50","-98.35","5","US Map","AllStates"
"32.7990","-86.8073","7","Alabama","AStates"
"61.5850","-152.2683","4","Alaska","AStates"
"-14.3331","-170.0000","10","American Samoa","AStates"
"34.200","-111.3877","7","Arizona","AStates"
"34.9513","-92.3809","7","Arkansas","AStates"

Answer (score 0):

This part of your  code is between `</head>` and `<body>`.... that is, OUTSIDE the `<body>` tag:

```
<ul>
    <li id="listModel" class="hidden"><a class="url"><span class="groupName"></span></a></li>

    <div id="groupModel" class="hidden"></div>
    <span id="stateModel" class="hidden" sname="name" lat="0.0" lon="0.0" zom="7"></span>
</ul>
```

Placing it inside `<body>` would be a good first step toward making this work :)

Comment: I'll do that...could be my Blonde showing, but for some reason I thought it needed to be in the head to keep it from ever showing up on the page. oh well..Thanks

Comment: your 'hidden' class should take care of hiding the element. By not placing your elements in the <body> you are leaving it up to the User Agent to decide where to place it. I think some UA's may place it inside <body> but anything could happen...it could be ignored. Best to place inside <body> if you want it to be correctly inserted in the DOM.  Let us know if this fixes it.

Comment: OK, after some hair-pulling and gnashing of teeth. I finally got something to actually work...kindof. It does work a little bit. I get ONE tab with all the tab headings in it, and all the data items in that tab's body...